# How to get two CSS rating star widgets to not affect each other when clicked

Tags: html, css

Thanks for taking a look...

Please see the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34bhp4w8/) that shows two CSS only rating star widgets or the code below. When you select a rating on the second widget, for some reason it always changes the rating on the first widget. Any idea where the error is in my CSS? Sorry if this is a basic question, I am not very good with CSS yet. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="stars">
  <div class="rating" style="width:65%"></div>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star5" value="5">
  <label for="star5"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star4" value="4">
  <label for="star4"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star3" value="3">
  <label for="star3"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star2" value="2">
  <label for="star2"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star1" value="1">
  <label for="star1"></label>
</div>
</br>
<div class="stars">
  <div class="rating" style="width:65%"></div>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star5" value="5">
  <label for="star5"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star4" value="4">
  <label for="star4"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star3" value="3">
  <label for="star3"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star2" value="2">
  <label for="star2"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star1" value="1">
  <label for="star1"></label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.stars{
    width: 130px;
    height: 26px;
    background: url(http://sandbox.bumbu.ru/ui/external/stars.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
    position: relative;
}

.stars .rating{
    height: 26px;
    background: url(http://sandbox.bumbu.ru/ui/external/stars.png) 0 -26px repeat-x;
}

.stars input{
    display: none;
}

.stars label{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 26px;
    width: 130px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.stars:hover label{
    display: block;
}
.stars label:hover{
    background: url(http://sandbox.bumbu.ru/ui/external/stars.png) 0 -52px repeat-x;
}

.stars label + input + label{width: 104px;}
.stars label + input + label + input + label{width: 78px;}
.stars label + input + label + input + label + input + label{width: 52px;}
.stars label + input + label + input + label + input + label + input + label{width: 26px;}

.stars input:checked + label{
    display: block;
    background: url(http://sandbox.bumbu.ru/ui/external/stars.png) 0 -52px repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Id's are unique](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/) in HTML. You can't have more than one element with the same id on the page and expect it to behave. This is exemplified by the behavior you are seeing. Since your label's have the for attribute set to the id's, the browser will check the input's for the first id it "sees", since it is only expecting one.

Each radio group also needs to have a unique `name` attribute, or all radios will be treated as a singe group and only one star will be able to be selected on the page.

So you need to change the id's for the second set of radios:

```
<div class="stars">
  <div class="rating" style="width:65%"></div>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star5" value="5">
  <label for="star5"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star4" value="4">
  <label for="star4"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star3" value="3">
  <label for="star3"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star2" value="2">
  <label for="star2"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star1" value="1">
  <label for="star1"></label>
</div>
</br>
<div class="stars">
  <div class="rating" style="width:65%"></div>
  <input type="radio" name="ratinga" id="star5a" value="5">
  <label for="star5a"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="ratinga" id="star4a" value="4">
  <label for="star4a"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="ratinga" id="star3a" value="3">
  <label for="star3a"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="ratinga" id="star2a" value="2">
  <label for="star2a"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="ratinga" id="star1a" value="1">
  <label for="star1a"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: You also need unique `name` attributes to make them function as separate groups. otherwise only one star can be selected across all of them

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Can you check your jsfiddle? I'd sends me to one with no changes.

Comment: Someone edited my question and added fiddle. As I don't have access to jsfiddle at work, I'll remove the link for now. Just make changes similar to the example code.